# Android WireMock Junit Rule and Non Junit Java Usage do not work

Tags: android, kotlin, junit4, wiremock

I want to write a test for an Android Application with WireMock Integration.
I tried using all 3 different Wiremock Integration approaches - 
 1. Writing a test with JUnit Rule
 2. Non-JUnit and general Java usage
 3. WireMock APIs against a standalone server

I could run my tests with WireMock APIs against a standalone server.
But since I cannot run on different ports dynamically with this approach, I moved to the other 2 approaches.

Below is the sample Kotlin code (with predefined ports)

For Junit Rule implementation

```
@Rule
@JvmField
var wireMockRule: WireMockRule = WireMockRule(8888)

@Test
fun exampleTest() {
    stubFor(WireMock.get(WireMock.urlPathEqualTo( "/requestURL"))
            .willReturn(WireMock.aResponse().withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .withStatus(200).withBody(responseString)))

    // App launch and test assertions

}
```

For Non-JUnit and general Java usage

```
@Before
fun setUp() {
    wireMockServer = WireMockServer(wireMockConfig().port(8888))
    wireMockServer.start()

    // Tried it by both commenting and uncommenting the following line
   // configureFor("localhost", wireMockServer.port())
}

@Test
fun exampleTest() {
    val wireMockClient = WireMock("localhost", wireMockServer.port())

    wireMockClient.register(stubFor(WireMock.get(WireMock.urlPathMatching( "/requestURL"))
            .willReturn(WireMock.aResponse().withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .withStatus(200).withBody(responseString))))

    // App launch and test assertions
}
```

For both these approaches, I am not getting the response I stubbed. I am getting an empty response. 
Changed the "withStatus" field to 400 to see if its an issue with response String, but I am not getting the error either, thats when I am sure that its not stubbing anything atall!

Is there anything I am missing from the sample codes shared?

Note: Junit version used is Junit4, writing the tests in Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the reason why the above implementation was not working.
My request calls were going to host and port 10.0.2.2 and 8080 by default(based on the existing code) and I am stubbing the wiremock calls on local host and 8888.
It started working as expected once the host and port for the request call is updated.